# Inserting XML block into existing XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm a bit of a newbie to XML. I have a class that creates an xml file (using Jaxb). So I have an existing xml file which contains the following.

```
<bookList>
  <book>
    <title> Grapes of Wrath </title>
    <author> John Steinbeck </author>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title> Harry Potter </title>
    <author> J.K. Rowling </author>
  </book>
<bookList>
```

In my Java code, I can create a new Book object no problem. But how so I add a new book with all the attributes inside the bookList block? Can I do that in Jaxb or do I need to use something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have a `BooksList` object generated by JAXB, that `BookList` object probably has a `List` of `Book`. Just add a new book to that list, and marshal the `BooksList` to get the XML.

Edit:
Adding a link to an example that does unmarshalling and marhsalling:
http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbay.html

Comment: sorry, i should clarify. The XML file has been created and saved. It's a separate class that is opening the file and wants to add the book block.

Comment: What do you mean? It doesn't matter what class it is that is saving the file. Read the XML (unmarshal), modify the JAXB objects, and save the XML, again (by marshalling)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the unmarshalling comment, I will try this out, thanks!